# How add label in Dockerfile with sbt project version?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, label, sbt

my `build.sbt`:

```
[...]

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

[...]
```

and my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV PROJECT_HOME /usr/src

ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.18
RUN curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip https://site-bla-bla.zip
RUN unzip sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip -d ops
CMD /ops/sbt/bin/sbt run

[...]
```

**What I want is:** add the field `LABEL` in **Dockerfile** with the project version defined in **build.sbt** file. Something like:

`LABEL version="*"` *1.0.0 = build.sbt file, version field

How Can I do this?